# Is there a way to find height of table after filling the cells in python-pptx?

Tags: python-pptx

I have to handle a table overflow scenario, so if the height of the table increases more than the slide's height I will add one more.

So I tried to find the height of the table after populating it but it is same as an empty table.

```
prs = Presentation('test.pptx')
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[1])
table_placeholder = slide.shapes[1]
shape = table_placeholder.insert_table(rows=8, cols=3)
table = shape.table

slide_table_dims = table_dims(table)
print(slide_table_dims)

table.cell(0, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(1, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(2, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(3, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(4, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(5, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(6, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(7, 0).text = 'very long text'
table.cell(7, 1).text = 'very long text'
slide_table_dims = table_dims(table)
print(slide_table_dims)
```

code to calculate table _dimension

def table_dims(table):

```
widths = []
heights = []

for column in table.columns:
    widths.append(column.width)
for row in table.rows:
    heights.append(row.height)

total_width = (sum(widths)/Inches(1))
total_height = (sum(heights)/Inches(1))
dims = (total_width, total_height)
return dims
```

Comment: There is no API support for this in `python-pptx`.

Comment: Thanks @scanny .  Fixing number of rows per slide can be a workaround to handle the overflow but that also does not provide guaranteed fail-safe if content of the rows makes the row-height grow. Any suggestion for some other workaround?

Comment: The space consumed by the text is determined by the rendering engine in PowerPoint (or other client like LibreOffice). So to approximate that you would need to render the text yourself, compute expected line breaks, and then calculate the vertical size. That's challenging to do in Python. You may be able to do better using the `win32com` interface which _might_ expose a height property on the table. This will only work in Windows of course, because it is actually running the PowerPoint application, which is what provides the rendering engine.